# Approximate an exponential factor

Tags: linear-algebra, exponential-function, systems-of-equations, approximation

What math methods can I use to approximate lambda in the following system of equations?:

$$ e^{-0.05\lambda}=0.5469\\
e^{-0.1 \lambda} = 0.3229\\
...\\
e^{-0.2 \lambda} = 0.1226$$

I am trying to fit an exponential curve to data.

Comment: That system is over-determined - note that $(e^{-.05\lambda})^2=e^{-.1\lambda}$, but the right hand sides of the equations don't bear that out. You'd have to be more specific about what kind of solution you're hoping for.

Comment: @MiloBrandt The OP is likely seeking some "best fit" for $\lambda$.  The question is "What is the definition of "best fit?"

Comment: Yes, I am looking for a best fit if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the set of equations, we have one parameter, $\lambda$, that we can adjust.  If one is looking for a "best fit" in the sense of mean-squared error, then one seeks the value of $\lambda$ that minimizes the function

$$f(\lambda)=\left(e^{-0.05\lambda}-0.5469\right)^2+\left(e^{-0.1\lambda}-0.3229\right)^2+\cdots +\left(e^{-0.2\lambda}-0.1226\right)^2 \tag 1$$

The solution to minimization of $(1)$ requires solving a highly non-linear equation for $\lambda$.

Another way forward that is tractable, is to first solve each of the original equations for $\lambda$ and then minimize the function

$$g(\lambda)=\left(\lambda +\frac{\log(0.5469)}{0.05}\right)^2+\left(\lambda+\frac{\log(0.3229)}{0.01}\right)^2+\cdots +\left(\lambda+\frac{\log(0.1226)}{0.2}\right)^2 \tag 2$$

Then, solution of the minimization of $(2)$ is simply the arithmetic average of the terms $\frac{\log(x_i)}{\alpha_i}$.

Comment: Thank you so much! I think I get it. I will be working it out and will write again if anything. Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  Just to be clear, the "best fit" is not a uniquely defined object.  In fact, the two approaches I outlined produce different values of $\lambda$.  I checked with the 3 data points and for the first approach got $\lambda \approx 11.40577$ while for the second approach $\lambda \approx 11.2894$.

Comment: I'm trying to up vote. I guess I won't let me because I don't have a full registration, which I'll try to obtain now.

Comment: Thank you!!  Much appreciative.

Comment: Nooo, when I confirm registration from my email, it resets my account, I.e. I lose all points and questions and start from scratch with a full registration. I managed to keep this tab open though . Does that mean I lose this account if I close this page?

Comment: I don't know the answer to that question.  Perhaps the system administrator would know how best to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

You have $n$ data points $x_i,y_i$ and you want to adjust $\lambda$ in order to get the best fit of your data using, as a model, $$y=e^{-\lambda x}$$ As pointed out by Dr. MV, the model is nonlinear with respect to the parameter and you need nonlinear regression to get the best parameter; most of the time, this will require a reasonable starting estimate.

Making the problem linear (using logarithms) gives the reasonable starting estimate. In your case, as Dr. MV showed, it is quite simple. But again, once this is done, you need to continue with nonlinear regression or optimization or Newton method to solve the problem. Remember that what is measured is $y$ and not $\log(y)$.

Just for illustration, I used the three data points and proceeded as described.

The first step gives $\lambda=10.7235$ and using it, the predicted values would be $0.5850,0.3422,0.1171$ which correspond to a sum of squares equal to $0.001853$.

Strating with this estimates, the full procedure leads to $\lambda=11.40585$ and using it, the predicted values would be $0.5654,0.3196,0.1022$ which correspond to a sum of squares equal to $0.000769$ which is basically $2.4$ times smaller than the previous one.

If you use Newton method for the problem, the iterates would be $$\lambda_0=10.7235$$ $$\lambda_1=11.3396$$ $$\lambda_2=11.4051$$ $$\lambda_3=11.4058$$